# how to subtract adjacent columns in an ssrs matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

[image: My SSRS Matrix]I have an ssrs matrix which looks like the one below :

```
               Month(Columns)
   Product(Rows)  Sales(Data)
```

The output looks something like this :

```
                       June  July  August  Sept  Oct  
          ABC          34     34     23     22    67
          DEF          33     21     32     22    14
```

I want an output that looks like this :

```
                       June  July  June-July  Aug  July-Aug  Sept  Aug-Sept  Oct  Sept-Oct
              ABC        34   34      0        23     11      22      1       67     45
              DEF        33   21      12       32     11      22      10      14     8
```

I tried doing something like this :

```
                Month(Columns) Change
   Product(Rows)  Sales(Data)   Expression
```

The expression looks something like this :

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!MONTH.Value=Fields!MONTH.Value,Fields!Products.Value,Nothing))-
Sum(IIF(Fields!MONTH.Value=Fields!MONTH.Value - 1,Fields!Products.Value,Nothing))
```

But it doesnt work . I want to see the output as shown above . Please let me know.

---

---

Hey Sam ,

With the solution you mentioned :

I see an output like this :

```
                       June   Garbage    July  July-June  Aug  Aug-Jul  
              ABC        34     xx        34      0        23     11    
              DEF        33     xx        21      12       32     11
```

Is there a way we can remove the column with the garbage values ?

Hey Sam , I tried your code. Now I have a big white space all along the column. Is there a way I can hide the wide space too ?
[image]

Comment: Hey I get an error saying : uses a previous function in an outer aggregate. Previous functions cannot be specifed as nested aggregates. My expression is something like this : =Sum(IIF(Fields!MONTH.Value=Fields!MONTH.Value,Fields!Products.Value,Nothing))-
Sum(IIF(Fields!MONTH.Value=Previous(Fields!MONTH.Value),Fields!Products.Value,Nothing))

Comment: What are the garbage values exactly? If you're grouping by a column in your dataset, then the column must relate to that data??  Have you checked your raw data?

Comment: The thing is , I actually want to hide the Garbage Column., because it might be doing a June-May , but May is not being displayed in my report. So I would like to hide the column if there is any way of doing it. I would like to hide only the first column thats calculating the difference? Was the question clear ?

Comment: how do you set your daterange in your dataset? do you have a date parameter that the user select?

Comment: I have a parameter for a Month with integer values 1,2,3,4 and another parameter for the Year 2013,2014 etc . The user selects the Month & Year from two different dropdowns

Comment: Ok.. And you have a Fields!MONTH.Value in your dataset? If the user selects say 4 for month (April) which month would you want hiding?

Comment: ahh.. I think I see, you would want the difference month column for April hiding...  Question on your report design.. Do you have two columns within each month group in your design?

Comment: Yes I have a Fields!MONTH.Value. If a user selects 4 . I choose the 4,3,2 to disply in my report. I do this by filtering based on the Month Parameter.  Month >= Parameters.Month.Value - 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42599/discussion-between-powercoder-and-sam)

Comment: Hey ! I was successful in adding the visibility expression.. But i see an empty space now , in the place of a column .. Would it be possible to get rid of the white space too ?

Comment: That's strange. Mine didn't do that when I tested it. Can you add an image of your table in design mode with the groupings showing?

Comment: I am using a matrix. I added the design in the question above at the top

Comment: I think that this question is deviating off topic and you should consider opening another question if you are having issues with hiding columns, as it's not really related to your initial question, (I think we've solved that?). But my suggestion would be to check the screen shot I sent you earlier, it had a merged cell at the top of the header across the two rows, you could try adding another row at the top and merging those cells.

Comment: hmm .. sure Let me try ! Thanks ! +1 and  Marked as answer

Comment: I added another question regarding this, Please take a look if you get time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413710/how-to-make-a-column-invisible-in-an-ssrs-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are grouping your columns by month then you don't need to use the SumIif

You can use a expression such as `=Sum(Fields!Products.Value)` to get the sum of all products in that particular month. If you want to see the difference between the current month and the previous month then if you enter the below expression in a cell within the month column group...

```
=Iif(Previous(Fields!MONTH.Value) = Nothing, 0, 
Sum(Fields!Products.Value) - Previous(Sum(Fields!Products.Value)))
```

You need the null check in this instance as the first month will return nothing for previous.

If you have overlapping row and column row groups (which I believe you do) then you won't be able to use Previous as it isn't supported :-(

---

I think that the only solution is to use some custom code.

There is a link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/347a66b1-4668-40e3-b7f8-6f175fe8ccfb/ssrs-2008r2-not-able-to-use-previous-aggregrate-function-in-matrix-columns-cell)

```
Public Shared previous as Integer
Public Shared current as Integer
  Public Shared Function GetCurrent(Item as Integer) as Integer
     previous=current
     current=Item
     return current
  End Function

  Public Shared Function GetPrevious()
     return previous
  End Function
```

Then your usage would be something like

```
=Code.GetCurrent(Sum(Fields!Products.Value)) - Code.GetPrevious()
```

Comment: Hey Sam ! Thank you very much for trying to help me . When I use the following expression I get the error message "The use of Previous aggregate function in a TablixCell within Tablix 'xyz' is not supported" I think whats causing the error is Previous(Fields!MONTH.Value) = Nothing,0

Comment: Hey Sam ! With the latest addition , I think we are almost there. But can you tell me how I can do the check here for the first month , since the first month doesnt have a previous ?

Comment: You could try setting previous to an initial value `Public Shared previous as Integer = -666` then you could check for that value, ie. `=iif(Code.GetPrevious() = -666,0,Code.GetCurrent(Sum(Fields!Products.Value)) - Code.GetPrevious())` I've not tested this but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey I tried the above solution , but I still see an output with a column of unwanted values. I have updated what I see in my question.Could you please tell me how I can get ride of the column with garbage values ?

Comment: What output did you see?

Comment: If you could please see my original question, I updated the output I see at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to calculate the differences between Matrix columns using the 'previous' function by adding the column grouping name.

```
=Previous(Sum(Fields!AMOUNT.Value),"PeriodGroupName")
```

Look here for a little more detail. 
http://www.tricks-and-tips.nl/tips-and-tricks/sql/ssrs/ssrs-matrix-compare-column-values
And here for the documentation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms156372(v=sql.105)

Comment: If you are not sure, then ask again as a comment or try to find a better solution so to be 100% sure. Please read the rules.

Comment: @dpap, Sorry, I have read to many replies 'you have not understood the question....' so was being polite.